# Dynamic queries with format() using the same argument many times

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I have a procedure which takes as input a suffix of a table's name. Then, using execute format(), I pass this parameter to execute the dynamic query. The problem is that this parameter is the same throughout - I do not want to pass it x times as such:

```
execute format('SELECT table_%s.field1, table_%s.field2,table_%s.field3
FROM table_%s', inTableSuffix, inTableSuffix, inTableSuffix, inTableSuffix, ...)
```

I would like a format similar to the following:

```
execute format('SELECT table_%s.field1, table_%s.field2,table_%s.field3
FROM table_%s', inTableSuffix)
```

I understand that I can solve this problem using an alias to the table name but is there another alternative?

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Answer (score 6):

You can *repeatedly* address the positional arguments like this:

---

```
execute format('SELECT table_%1$s.field1
   , table_%1$s.field2,table_%1$s.field3
FROM table_%1$s;', inTableSuffix);
```

---

Note: in this particular case, you can avoid repeating yourself by using an alias:

---

```
execute format('SELECT tx.field1
   , tx.field2, tx.field3
FROM table_%s tx;', inTableSuffix);
```

Comment: Also, there is no need to use the table name for each column if there is not a join, but even if there a join you can use alias to the table, so there not need to concat multiple times the full table name.

Answer (score 1):

[@wildplasser already provided the syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41651607/939860) how to reference the same parameter repeatedly in `format()`. The code is still dangerous, though. You ***need*** to escape identifiers built from user input:

```
EXECUTE format('SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM %I', 'table_' || inTableSuffix);
```

For the given example, you only need the parameter once anyway. The scope of dynamic queries executed with `EXECUTE` in plpgsql is limited to the query itself. Other variables or parameters of the function are *not* visible inside `EXECUTE`. Hence, there is not need to table-qualify columns in a dynamic query with a single table in the `FROM` clause.

But more importantly, [`%I` is used in  `format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) for identifiers to avoid syntax errors, misguided lower-casing or, worse, SQL injection! It double-quotes (only!) otherwise illegal identifiers, [just like `quote_ident()` would](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-QUOTE-LITERAL-EXAMPLE).

Details:

- [SQL injection in Postgres functions vs prepared queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49699/sql-injection-in-postgres-functions-vs-prepared-queries/49718#49718)
- [Demonstrate SQL injection in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41686393/demonstrate-sql-injection-in-pl-pgsql/41688244#41688244)
- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

Comment: @wildplasser: You seem to be missing that I do that already. No need for a (more expensive) variable, you can pass the concatenated expression as parameter. Aside: it's `quote_ident()`, not `quote_identifier()`.

Comment: Oops, I didn't see that.