# Demonstrate SQL injection in PL/pgSQL

Tags: postgresql, sql-injection, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I have this function in plpgsql:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function login_v(em varchar, passwd varchar)
  RETURNS users AS $$
DECLARE
   cu users;
BEGIN
   SELECT * into cu
   FROM users where email = em 
   AND encrypted_password = crypt(passwd, encrypted_password);

   return cu;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I provide an input like this: `select login_v('test@test.com'' OR 1=1;--','la la la');`, I think my method should return the user with email  `test@test.com`. What Am I doing wrong?

Performing SQL injection is necessary here to demonstrate the concept for an exercise, but I am an SQL injection and plpgsql boob. :|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL queries in PL/pgSQL are planned like prepared statements. As long as you only pass ***values*** like you do, SQL injection is generally ***impossible***. Details:

- [SQL injection in Postgres functions vs prepared queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/49718/3684)

Use dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE` and without proper parameter handling to actually demonstrate SQL injection.

Like (this is how ***not*** to do it!):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION login_v(em varchar, passwd varchar)
  RETURNS SETOF users
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
      'SELECT *
       FROM   users
       WHERE  email = $1
       AND    encrypted_password = crypt(''' || passwd || ''', encrypted_password)'
   USING em;
END
$func$;
```

The first variable `em` is properly passed with the `USING` clause as ***value*** and thus cannot be abused for SQL injection.

But the second variable `passwd` is concatenated without quoting properly. Thus, user input can be converted to SQL code. SQL injection.

**Never do this!** Except when demonstrating how not to do it.

Similar mischief is possible when concatenating SQL strings in the client improperly.