# Doesn't find variable when passing query as parameter

Tags: postgresql, parameters, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I have a function with a static output that works. (Postgres v.10)
This returns the Amount of users per Server.

Here is the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test()
 RETURNS SETOF record
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    var_req TEXT;
    var_error text;
    rec_key record;
    cur_key CURSOR FOR Select s.srv,s.host,s.port from public.connections() s where s.online = true;
BEGIN
open cur_key;
loop
   fetch cur_key into rec_key;
   EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;

var_req := 
'Select * from dblink(
''host=' || rec_key.host || '
port=' || rec_key.port || '
user=**
password=**
dbname=mydb'',
''
select '''''|| rec_key.srv ||''''' as srv ,count (*) as total from users '') as (srv varchar,total integer)
';
return query execute var_req;  
end loop;
close cur_key;
END 
$function$
;
```

Output =

```
srv      total
rp1       50
sr2       41
xy        100
```

To be able to use reuse this query i want to move out the sql part so that i can pass it as parameter.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test2(text)
 RETURNS SETOF record
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    var_req TEXT;
    var_error text;
    rec_key record;
    cur_key CURSOR FOR Select s.srv,s.host,s.port from public.connections() s where s.online = true;
BEGIN
open cur_key;
loop
   fetch cur_key into rec_key;
   EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;

var_req := 
'Select * from dblink(
''host=' || rec_key.host || '
port=' || rec_key.port || '
user=**
password=**
dbname=**'',
''
' || $1 || '
';
return query execute var_req;  
end loop;
close cur_key;
END 
$function$
;
```

Now when i try to make exact the same query with the dynamic function i don't get it to work.
Like this i am pretty close to my goal but instead of using what's inside the rec_key.srv variable it returns  '''''|| rec_key.srv ||'''''  :(

```
select * from public.test2('select ''''''''''''|| rec_key.srv ||'''''''''''' as srv ,count (*) as total from users '') as (srv varchar,total integer)') as (srv varchar,total integer)
```

Output =

```
            srv                   total
'''''|| rec_key.srv ||'''''        50
'''''|| rec_key.srv ||'''''        41
'''''|| rec_key.srv ||'''''        100
```

Can someone explain me how i can call what's inside the variable rec_key.srv with the new function?

Comment: Strong advice to use the `format()` function to build the dynamic query.

Comment: @wildplasser can you please show how i can implement that in my code and why should i use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boils down to just this: (!)

```sql
SELECT s.srv, t.*
FROM   public.connections() s
     , dblink('host=' || s.host || ' port=' || s.port || ' user=** password=** dbname=**'
            , 'SELECT count(*) FROM users') AS t(total integer);
```

No wrapper function, no dynamic SQL, no cursor.
Just execute dblink() in an implicit `CROSS JOIN LATERAL`.

I also added `srv` to the result like you have in your first function. No need to pipe that through dblink.

See:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

Passing arbitrary queries is **open to SQL injection**. Be sure to understand possible implications and only execute it with trusted input. See:

- [Demonstrate SQL injection in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41686393/demonstrate-sql-injection-in-pl-pgsql/41688244#41688244)
- https://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time and help me! Had to take away srv text, to make it work though. Now it works like a charm. 

SELECT s.srv, t.*
FROM   public.connections() s
     , dblink('host=' || s.host || ' port=' || s.port || ' user=** password=** dbname=**'
            , 'SELECT count(*)  FROM users') AS t(total integer);

Comment: @user2210516 Yes, that was left over from before I broke out `srv`. Fixed now.

Comment: I don't really understand that how i know how i can change the s.host, and s.port with thoose $ symbol. would this work? SELECT s.srv, t.*
FROM   public.connections() s
     , dblink('host=' || 1$ || ' port=' || 2$ || ' user=** password=** dbname=**'
            , 'SELECT count(*) FROM users') AS t(total integer);

Comment: @user2210516 No `$` here. You might be thinking of my other answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71656813/939860