# How to nest variable in query string passed to function

Tags: postgresql, parameter-passing, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I need to be able to get the value stored inside `rec_key.empname` when I call this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.txt(text)
 RETURNS SETOF record
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare
    var_param text;
    var_req TEXT;
    rec_key record;
    cur_key CURSOR FOR Select empname::varchar from employee;
BEGIN
open cur_key;
loop
   fetch cur_key into rec_key;
   EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
var_req := 
'
' || $1 || '
';
return query execute var_req;  
end loop;
close cur_key;
END 
$function$
;
```

What do I have to change to get the desired `empname` when calling the function?

If I call it like this it doesn't work: :(

```
select * from public.txt('select empid, age::integer,''''''|rec_key.empname|''''''::varchar from employee') as (empid integer, age integer, empname varchar)
```

[image]

Comment: Your function is defined as `public.txt`, but you call `public.grem_txt`. But first, tell us what you *really* need. You certainly don't need anything like you show here. Looks like you want to execute a passed  `SELECT` query repeatedly with `employee.empname` added somehow? Start by declaring your version of Postgres, then (the relevant part or) the table definition for `employee`, and then describe your actual objective.

Comment: Hallo @erwinbrandstetter ! Actually i posted another queston before with the infos you ask for but i got no response so i rewrote the question to be more simpler. Here is this first one. Please have a look at this one and tell me if you need more information. I would really appreciate your help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71585308/doesnt-find-variable-when-passing-query-as-parameter

Answer (score 1):

To address the question asked:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.txt(_sql text)
  RETURNS SETOF record
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _rec record;
BEGIN
   FOR _rec IN 
      SELECT empname::text FROM employee
   LOOP
      RETURN QUERY EXECUTE _sql
      USING _rec.empname;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM public.txt('SELECT empid, age::integer, $1 AS empname FROM employee')
       AS (empid integer, age integer, empname varchar);
```

The example does not make any sense, though, and all of it could be replaced with a simple query. See my anser to your earlier question:

- [Doesn't find variable when passing query as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71585308/doesnt-find-variable-when-passing-query-as-parameter/71656219#71656219)

Use the much simpler implicit cursor of a `FOR` loop. See:

- [Cursor based records in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22339628/cursor-based-records-in-postgresql/22340544#22340544)
- [Truncating all tables in a Postgres database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829158/truncating-all-tables-in-a-postgres-database/12082038#12082038)

Pass the variable as *value* with a `USING` clause. `$1` is the symbol to reference the first `USING` argument. See:

- [Replace double quotes with single quotes in Postgres (plpgsql)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37288759/replace-double-quotes-with-single-quotes-in-postgres-plpgsql/37288895#37288895)