# `EXECUTE` statement VS no `EXECUTE` statement in a function in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql, execute

I created `person` table, then inserted 2 rows into it as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (
  id INT,
  name VARCHAR(20),
  age INT
);

INSERT INTO person (id, name, age) 
VALUES (1, 'John', 27), (2, 'David', 32);
```

Then with an [EXECUTE statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN), I created `my_func()` with `my_age` and `my_id` parameter as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(my_age INT, my_id INT) RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN                -- ↑↑↑↑↑↑      ↑↑↑↑↑
  EXECUTE 'UPDATE person SET age = $1 WHERE id = $2' USING my_age, my_id;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Or:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(my_age INT, my_id INT) RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE 'UPDATE person SET age = $1 WHERE id = $2' USING $1, $2;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, calling `my_func()` could update `age` of `David` to `56` as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func(56, 2);
 my_func
---------

(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT * FROM person;
 id | name  | age
----+-------+-----
  1 | John  |  27
  2 | David |  56
(2 rows)
```

Next without an `EXECUTE` statement, I created `my_func()` with `my_age` and `my_id` parameter as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(my_age INT, my_id INT) RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN                -- ↑↑↑↑↑↑      ↑↑↑↑↑
  UPDATE person SET age = my_age WHERE id = my_id;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Or:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(my_age INT, my_id INT) RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
  UPDATE person SET age = $1 WHERE id = $2;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, calling `my_func()` could update `age` of `David` to `56` as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func(56, 2);
 my_func
---------

(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT * FROM person;
 id | name  | age
----+-------+-----
  1 | John  |  27
  2 | David |  56
(2 rows)
```

So, what is the difference between the function with and without an `EXECUTE` statement?

Comment: The correct reply is from Erwin Brandstetter. `EXECUTE` uses one shot plan, embedded SQL uses specific heuristic that chooses between one shot plan and generic plan.

Answer (score 5):

#### When to use `EXECUTE`?

[`EXECUTE` in PL/pgSQL is used for **dynamic SQL**.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) For building and executing SQL statements on the fly. Mainly to involve input from users or system catalogs in other roles than just *values* - i.e. *identifiers* other *key words* of the [SQL syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html). You don't normally use `EXECUTE` unless you need *that*.

One exception: While PL/pgSQL can save and reuse a generic query plan for SQL DML statements (much like prepared statements, but only after a couple of executions, there is some sophistication to this), `EXECUTE` prevents that from happening and forces **a new query plan for every execution**. And that can be (ab)used for highly irregular data distributions, where the query plan is better optimized for the given input (and Postgres does not realize this all by itself).

Since Postgres 12, you can also use the server variable [`plan_cache_mode`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-PLAN-CACHE-MODE) to force generic or custom plans for non-dynamic DML statements.

It's hard to imagine this could make sense for your simple example. If `person.id` is the PK, it certainly doesn't. Basically, your version with `EXECUTE` is nonsense.

Related:

- [Function Performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/8189/3684)
- [LANGUAGE SQL vs LANGUAGE plpgsql in PostgreSQL functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755468/language-sql-vs-language-plpgsql-in-postgresql-functions/24771561#24771561)

Always concatenate dynamic SQL carefully to defend against possible **SQL injection**! See:

- [SQL injection in Postgres functions vs prepared queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/49718/3684)
- [Demonstrate SQL injection in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41686393/demonstrate-sql-injection-in-pl-pgsql/41688244#41688244)

One other side effect: The query string passed to `EXECUTE` executes in a separate scope. Variables and parameters of the surrounding code block are not visible there. (Preferably passed in as *values* with the `USING` clause.) Good to know, but don't abuse dynamic SQL just to hide naming collisions.

#### Hidden issue: naming conflicts

There are better solutions to resolve naming conflicts with function parameters. [The manual has an overview.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-VAR-SUBST)

Ideally, adopt a naming convention that avoids conflicts altogether.
If that's not an option, the simple fix is to table-qualify all column names (which is never a bad idea) and reference function parameters by ordinal position: `$1` etc.

##### Simple solution

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc(id int, age int)  -- ①
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
UPDATE person p SET age = $2 WHERE p.id = $1;  -- ②
$func$;
```

① While the function doesn't return anything, you might just use a procedure instead. Either way, we have parameter names colliding with column names.

② References to ordinal positions of function parameters avoid ambiguity.

##### Alternative to demonstrate more options

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(id int, age int)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
#variable_conflict use_variable    -- ③
BEGIN
   UPDATE person p    -- table alias for brevity
   SET    age = age   -- ④, ⑤
   WHERE  p.id = id;  -- ⑥, ⑤
END
$func$;
```

Using a function like you had it. Just as proof of concept.

③ `#variable_conflict use_variable` before the begin of the function body resolves ambiguities in favor of parameter or variable names. Typically unnecessary.

④ Target columns of an `UPDATE` are never ambiguous and cannot be table-qualified.

⑤ The ambiguous, unqualified names `age` and `id` resolve to function parameters due to `#variable_conflict use_variable`.

⑥ `p.id` is table-qualified and hence unambiguous.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HArMH9T7)

Related:

- [How to return result of a SELECT inside a function in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945932/how-to-return-result-of-a-select-inside-a-function-in-postgresql/7945958#7945958)
- [PL/pgSQL column name the same as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29600500/pl-pgsql-column-name-the-same-as-variable/29604751#29604751)

<sub>Aside, `age` as table column is typically nonsense. Store a birthday instead.</sub>

Answer (score -2):

With an [EXECUTE statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html), you can create `my_func()` with `age` and `id` parameter which are the same names as `age` and `id` column as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(age INT, id INT) RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN                -- ↑↑↑      ↑↑
  EXECUTE 'UPDATE person SET age = $1 WHERE id = $2' USING age, id;
END;                      -- ↑↑↑            ↑↑
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Or:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(age INT, id INT) RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN                -- ↑↑↑      ↑↑
  EXECUTE 'UPDATE person SET age = $1 WHERE id = $2' USING $1, $2;
END;                      -- ↑↑↑            ↑↑
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, calling `my_func()` could update `age` of `David` to `56` as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func(56, 2);
 my_func
---------

(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT * FROM person;
 id | name  | age
----+-------+-----
  1 | John  |  27
  2 | David |  56
(2 rows)
```

And without an `EXECUTE` statement, you can still create `my_func()` with `age` and `id` parameter which are the same names as `age` and `id` column as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(age INT, id INT) RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN                -- ↑↑↑      ↑↑
  UPDATE person SET age = age WHERE id = id;
END;                   -- ↑↑↑       ↑↑
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Or:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(age INT, id INT) RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN                -- ↑↑↑      ↑↑
  UPDATE person SET age = $1 WHERE id = $2;
END;             -- ↑↑↑            ↑↑
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But, calling `my_func()` above gets [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821121/sql-column-reference-id-is-ambiguous#77811511) below:

> ERROR:  column reference "id" is ambiguous

Comment: Dynamic SQL just to hide naming collisions? Don't.

Comment: Without a naming convention, you will always get into trouble. That's not related to a function or how to use EXECUTE.

Comment: Using dynamic SQL as solution of conflict variables is really bad design. Use aliases, use own naming convention, but not dynamic SQL - it can be pretty confusing, and probably (not always) with negative performance impact.